# How to customize buildbot web pages

Tags: html, web, buildbot

I am trying to make some extra web pages for a test buildbot, since I am planning to have one running my project.

Practically I would like to have a waterfall page that show the button to build a specific builder, close to the build name, instead than in the builder page only. I would also like to have some reference documents loaded from inside the builder work folder, and from other locations on the slave machine; using buttons to display or hide them.

I've looked at the manual and I do not see any info about how do you customize or create new html pages, that can leverage on the Buildbot features (like the templates already included with Buildbot do).

I have opened some pages, and see that there are some html files that actually has non-html code statements like

```
% macro
% for
```

And so on. I am not a web programmer so I am quite clueless about what should I look for. Tried to google the word `macro` for HTML and I just got a bunch of results related to Wiki customization; it does not look like it is Python language so I am quite lost.

Is there anyone that was successfully able to make custom pages for the buildbot, and could give me some pointers about what to learn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Buildbot uses jinja2 for templating, the jinja2 homepage has some nice documentation. This is where the non-html statements come from. I found google's chromium buildbot to be a good starting point, when learning about buildbot customization.

- http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/0.8.7/developer/webstatus.html
- http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs
- http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/tools/build/masters/master.chromium/templates/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally I can make sense of that code written in the pages...it was looking like a mix of python and html. Is there any visual editor to work with this kind of language? I am just trying to add few fields and move around the fields, to fit my idea. Thanks!

Comment: The code diffs in the chromium templates project might show some insight into how the fields interact:

http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/tools/build/masters/master.chromium/templates/build.html?view=diff&r1=206310&r2=89637&diff_format=h

Comment: Note, this has changed pretty drastically in version 0.9, and none of these guides are valid anymore.